# How do you insert data into a specific column in SQlite database?

Tags: python, database, list, sqlite

I have a list of variables. I want to go through each of the elements in the list and add it to the rows of a column. However, when I update my table and open my database, nothing shows in the column (only null).

When I add the list into the column, my goal is then do some analysis on the data. I am doing a project for school where one of the components is to pass/fail students and give them a corresponding grade.

I'm working with Python idle and Database for SQlite.
I've tried iterating through the list and getting each value into the next row for the column.
I've tried through all different syntax (e.g %s, (?)...)

```
        for i, val in enumerate (b):
            c.execute("UPDATE class SET percentage = (?) WHERE first = (?)",(val,(i+1)))
            conn.commit()
```

When I've cleared through the syntax message, and get no errors, i check my database and there is nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

print the update statement to see if all is well.  Move the commit outside the for loop.  Example at (MySql) https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_update.asp

---

```
for i, val in enumerate (b):
    print("UPDATE class SET percentage = (?) WHERE first = (?)",(val,(i+1))
    c.execute("UPDATE class SET percentage = (?) WHERE first = (?)",(val,(i+1)))
    conn.commit() #move to outside for loop, call commit once
```

---

added answer

Python prepared sql uses '%s' for variables, change from the question mark.
So

---

```
 c.execute("UPDATE class SET percentage = (?) WHERE first = (?)",(val,(i+1)))
```

---

should be

---

```
 c.execute("UPDATE class SET percentage = (%s) WHERE first = (%s)",(val,(i+1)))
```

---

PHP script with create, insert, update then select.  Try 1 update at a time then add another, etc...

---

input

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql[0] = "drop table classes;";
if ($conn->query($sql[0]) === TRUE) {
    echo "Script successful";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$sql[1] = "CREATE TABLE classes (class_no integer,percentage text,weekday text, date_percent date);";
if ($conn->query($sql[1]) === TRUE) {
    echo "Script successful";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$sql[2] = "INSERT INTO classes VALUES(1, '100', 'Tuesday', '2019-10-01' );";
if ($conn->query($sql[2]) === TRUE) {
    echo "Script successful";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$sql[3] = "INSERT INTO classes VALUES(2, '90', 'Wednesday', '2019-10-02' );";
if ($conn->query($sql[3]) === TRUE) {
    echo "Script successful";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}



$sql = "SELECT class_no, percentage, weekday FROM classes";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<br>Class No: " . $row["class_no"]. " Percentage: " . $row["percentage"]. " Weekday: " . $row["weekday"]."    <br><br>";
    }
} else {

    echo "0 results";
}


$sql_u = "Update classes set percentage = '100' where class_no = 2;";
if ($conn->query($sql_u) === TRUE) {
    echo "Script update successful";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$sql = "";
$sql = "SELECT class_no, percentage, weekday FROM classes";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<br>Class No: " . $row["class_no"]. " Percentage: " . $row["percentage"]. " Weekday: " . $row["weekday"]."    <br><br>";
    }
} else {

    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

output:

Script successfulScript successfulScript successfulScript successful
Class No: 1 Percentage: 100 Weekday: Tuesday 


Class No: 2 Percentage: 90 Weekday: Wednesday 

Script update successful
Class No: 1 Percentage: 100 Weekday: Tuesday 


Class No: 2 Percentage: 100 Weekday: Wednesday
```

Comment: The print statement came seemed to work and came out like this:            
UPDATE class SET percentage = (?) WHERE first = (?) (99, 1)
UPDATE class SET percentage = (?) WHERE first = (?) (98, 2)
UPDATE class SET percentage = (?) WHERE first = (?) (97, 3)
UPDATE class SET percentage = (?) WHERE first = (?) (96, 4)
UPDATE class SET percentage = (?) WHERE first = (?) (76, 5)
UPDATE class SET percentage = (?) WHERE first = (?) (90, 6)
UPDATE class SET percentage = (?) WHERE first = (?) (78, 7)                                  But it still hasn't updated the database.

Comment: Make sure your userid for the database has update privledges. For Mysql the command is:

    SHOW GRANTS [FOR user]